# cannot use address (type string) as type AccountAddress in assignment

Tags: go

I'm facing an issue while assignment of a string with a type of `type AccountAddress [16]uint8`.

```
type AccountAddress [16]uint8

address := c.Param("adress")
var account AccountAddress
account = address
```

```
Error cannot use address (type string) as type AccountAddress in assignment
```

Tried:

```
 var account diemtypes.AccountAddress
 account = []uint8(address)
```

```
Error cannot use ([]uint8)(address) (type []uint8) as type diemtypes.AccountAddress in assignment
```

Can anyone please help me in this.

Comment: according to your type definition, the value you assign to `AccountAddress` must be an array of 16 8bit unsigned integers, not a string. what's the value of `address`? if this string encodes to 16 bytes, you might be able to convert (not sure though if that makes sense in your context).

Comment: @MrFuppes `address` is a string which contains random string

Comment: `copy(account[:], c.Param("adress"))`

Answer (score 1):

Here you are confusing many basic things thing. Let me clear them on by one

1. In golang custom types are treated as separate types even both are defined with the same built-in type

For example

```
    type StringType1 string 
    type StringType2 string
    
    var name1 StringType1="Umar"
    var name2 StringType2="Hayat"
    
    fmt.Println("StringType1 : ", name1)
    fmt.Println("StringType2 : ", name2)
```

The output of the above code is https://play.golang.org/p/QDcaM1IolbJ

```
StringType1 :  Umar
StringType2 :  Hayat
```

Here we have two custom types `StringType1` and `StringType2 both are defined by`  string`. But we can not assign a variable of these two types to each other directly until we convert them to the required type e.g

```
    name1=name2
```

Output

```
cannot use name2 (type StringType2) as type StringType1 in assignment
```

Similar is the case with your code. You are converting a `string` to a custom type without applying conversion.

2. Second you are trying to convert a `string` to a byte array of fixed length 15 and type `uint8`. This can be done as mentioned by @Cerise Limon

```
copy(account[:], c.Param("adress"))
```

But keep one thing here in mind you are copying `string` to `unit8` type so you should not expect characters in `account` instead it will be ASCI values of that string character. I hope it will clear all your miss conceptions.

Answer (score 0):

A string can be implicitly converted to a []uint8, but this is a slice and [16]uint8 is an array. Those are distinct and incompatible types. However, you can copy the contents of the slice to an array using `copy()` function.

See an example here: https://play.golang.org/p/5zHg8Me-3KO

Comment: Can you please give me an example.

Comment: I updated my post with a playground example